# Assigning values from Dictionary to dynamic object C#

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, dynamic

There is a Dictionary with values. It needs to assign each value to the dynamic instance property. And the name of dynamic variable property should be the same as dictionary's key. 
Something like this:

```
dynamic response = new ExpandoObject();
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
string s;
dict.TryGetValue("Name", out s); // imagine dictionary contains some data
response.Name = s;
dict.TryGetValue("Street", out s);
response.Street = s;
....
```

I am sure there is some more efficient way then just to iterate each value. If to create for-loop how to describe dynamic instance property name each time? Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ExpandoObject` implements `IDictionary<string, object>` since that's how it stores "property" values, so you can just do:

```
var response = new ExpandoObject();
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
// imagine dict contains some data
foreach(var kvp in dict)
{
     (response as IDictionary<string, object>)[kvp.Key] = kvp.Value;
}
```

Note that I don't use `dynamic` here since you aren't accessing the `ExpandoObject`'s properties dynamically. It may not make a huge difference in isolation but if you use this method often it may improve the performance overall since the indexer will be bound at compile-time instead of at run-time.

Comment: Got this exception  "Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject'"

Comment: @OlegIaremchuk   do it as :  (response as IDictionary<string, object>)[kvp.Key] = kvp.Value;

Comment: @MaksimSimkin perfect. Thank you